# adding AsyncTask to onClick listener

Tags: java, android, json

I have made program which works with AsyncTask it prints a list of the JSON data when program is executed, but the problem is that I want it to execute when I press the button. How do I get the results of AsyncTask into my onClick Button Listener ? How do I call AsyncTask from onClick?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {


    double[] avstand;
    JSONArray jArray;
    LocationManager lm;
    TextView lt, ln;
    String provider;
    Location l;
    ListView list;
    StasjonAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Stasjoner> stasjonListe;
    Button nButton;
    TextView test;
    GPSTracker gps;
    Stasjoner stasjon;
    double minValue;
    String geoUri;
    Button instButton;
    Button bildeButton;
    Button kjorTil;
    Button visListe;
    File mPhotoFile;
    Uri mPhotoFileUri;
    String mDisplayFolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ln=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.visLong);
        test=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
        lt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.visLati);

        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            // \n is for new line
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
   //get latitude and longitude of the location
            double lat= gps.getLatitude();
            double lng= gps.getLongitude();
            //display on text view
            ln.setText(""+lng);
            lt.setText(""+lat);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        stasjonListe = new ArrayList<Stasjoner>();
        nButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        instButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.instillinger);
        bildeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bildeButton);
        kjorTil= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        visListe = (Button)findViewById(R.id.visListe);
        //new StasjonAsyncTask().execute("http://hotell.difi.no/?dataset=porsgrunn/elbilparkering?");       blogas url, jis grazina html puslapi, reikia daryt requesta i api endpoint, kuris grazina json
        new StasjonAsyncTask().execute("http://hotell.difi.no/api/json/porsgrunn/elbilparkering?");

        instButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Instillinger.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        nButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int value = (int) getMinValue(avstand);
                test.setText(stasjonListe.get(value).getLatitude().toString());
                test.setText(stasjonListe.get(value).getLongtitude().toString());
                String geoURI = "geo:" + stasjonListe.get(value).getLatitude().toString() + ","+ stasjonListe.get(value).getLongtitude().toString() + "?z=";
                Uri geo = Uri.parse(geoURI);
                Intent geoMap = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,geo);
                startActivity(geoMap);
            }
        });

        visListe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //StasjonAsyncTask

            }
        });

        bildeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomCameraActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        kjorTil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + gps.getLatitude() +"," + gps.getLongitude() + "&daddr=" + Double.parseDouble(stasjon.getLatitude()) +","+Double.parseDouble(stasjon.getLongtitude())));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }


    public class StasjonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urls[0]);    api endpointas nepriima post requestu, pakeiciam i get
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if(status == 200) {
                     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
                    jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("entries");
                    avstand = new double[jArray.length()];

                    for(int i=0;i< jArray.length();i++){
                        stasjon = new Stasjoner();

                        JSONObject jRealObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                        stasjon.setId(jRealObject.getString("id"));
                        stasjon.setKapasitet(jRealObject.getString("kapasitet"));
                        stasjon.setPlassering(jRealObject.getString("plassering"));
                        stasjon.setTilgjengelighet(jRealObject.getString("tilgjengelighet"));
                        stasjon.setBeskrivelse(jRealObject.getString("beskrivelse"));
                        stasjon.setNavn(jRealObject.getString("navn"));
                        stasjon.setLongtitude(jRealObject.getString("longitude"));
                        stasjon.setLatitude(jRealObject.getString("latitude"));
                        stasjon.setTilgang(jRealObject.getString("tilgang"));
                        stasjon.setTidsbegrensing(jRealObject.getString("tidsbegrensing"));

                        double dist = distance(Double.parseDouble(stasjon.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(stasjon.getLongtitude()), gps.getLatitude(),gps.getLongitude(), 'K');
                        stasjon.setAvstand(Double.toString(dist));

                       avstand[i]= dist;

                        stasjonListe.add(stasjon);
                    }
                    return true;


                }




            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Arrays.sort(avstand);

            minValue = getMinValue(avstand);

            //test.setText(Double.toString(minValue));
            if(result== false){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                StasjonAdapter adapter = new StasjonAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.rad, stasjonListe);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
            double theta = lon1 - lon2;
            double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
            dist = Math.acos(dist);
            dist = rad2deg(dist);
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
            if (unit == 'K') {
                dist = dist * 1.609344;
            } else if (unit == 'N') {
                dist = dist * 0.8684;
            }
            return (dist);
        }
        private double deg2rad(double deg) {
            return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
        }
        private double rad2deg(double rad) {
            return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
        }
    }

    public static double getMinValue(double[] numbers){
        double minValue = numbers[0];
        int minValueIndex = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){
            if(numbers[i] < minValue){
                minValue = numbers[i];
                minValueIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minValueIndex;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not create a separate account to ask a worse version of your previous question. Instead, respond to the comments given and help us help you

Answer (score 0):

in your StasjonAsyncTask make activity class variable. 
and give it's instance when you are creating StasjonAsyncTask variable

```
public class StasjonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
private MainActivity myActivity;

public StasjonAsyncTask(MainActivity myActivity){
this.myActivity=myActivity;
}
...
```

on creating StasjonAsyncTask give activity instance

```
new StasjonAsyncTask(this).execute("http://hotell.difi.no/api/json/porsgrunn/elbilparkering?");
```

in your `onPostExecute` now you can call any function of your activity. 
Also separate `onClick` listener to another variable, will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
 visListe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //StasjonAsyncTask
          new StasjonAsyncTask().execute("http://hotell.difi.no/api/json/porsgrunn/elbilparkering?");

        }
    });
```

Comment: how to start it new activity?

Comment: you can call it in method onPostExecute, which will get call after parsing is done..!

Comment: not work, and you need put try catch is a concurrent thread !